# Laravel middleware with prefix not working

Tags: laravel, middleware, prefix

Currently I am working with a new project with laravel. For this project I need to add prefix for a group of routes and need to add the prefix by using middleware. The middleware is -

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $segments = $request->segments();

        if( $request->is('admin/*') ){
            return $next($request);
        }
        array_unshift($segments,'admin');
        return redirect()->to(implode('/',$segments));
    }
```

And my routes/web.php file is-

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin','prefix' => 'admin'],function(){
    Route::get('segments',function(){
       return request()->segments();
    });
});
```

But unfortunately this is not working for me. The middleware not force redirect me if I don't add admin/ prefix manually. But if I remove `'prefix' => 'admin'` from the route group then it works. How can I solve this problem?

**Sorry, for my bad English.**

Comment: Route::get('/segments') Add / before get request

Comment: Not working. :( @ManiruzzamanAkash

Comment: What's the use case for this? It seems like you are trying to redirect user away when user is in `admin/*` route? Perhaps we can give you a better answer if you can describe what's the purpose of this code?

Comment: My purpose is if we hit a route `domain.com/segments` then it redirects to `domain.com/admin/segments` and the route also allow the `/admin` prefix. @LionelChan

Answer (score 0):

This approach will not work for you because you're only applying the middleware to the `admin/*` routes.

If you want to redirect a user from any not `admin/*` routes to `admin` ones, you could do something like this instead. Add this route to the end of the `web.php`:

```
Route::get('{param1?}/{param2?}/{param3?}', 'RedirectController@redirectoToAdmin');
```

Create `RedirectController` controller and do this:

```
public function redirectoToAdmin()
{
    return redirect('admin/' . request()->path());
}
```

Also, remove the `admin` middleware from the route group you've shown.

Comment: But what if I want to do this for some specific routes?

Comment: @Sajeeb then you should create a few routes. For example, if you want to redirect only `dash/*` routes to  `admin/dash/*`, create this route `'dash/{param1?}/{param2?}'`. Then create similar route for any URI you want to redirect to `admin/*`